# NSFileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath encoding problem with samba path

Tags: cocoa, encoding, samba, nsfilemanager

i mount a SMB path using this code

```
urlStringOfVolumeToMount = [urlStringOfVolumeToMount stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
NSURL *urlOfVolumeToMount = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStringOfVolumeToMount];
FSVolumeRefNum returnRefNum;
FSMountServerVolumeSync( (CFURLRef)urlOfVolumeToMount, NULL, NULL, NULL, &returnRefNum, 0L);
```

Then, i get the content of some paths :

```
NSMutableArray *content = (NSMutableArray *)[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
```

My problem is every path in "content" array containing special chars (ü for example) give me 2 chars encoded : ü becomes u¨

when i log bytes using :

```
[contentItem dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

it gives me : 75cc88 which is u (75) and ¨(cc88)

What i expected is the ü char encoded in utf-8. In bytes, it should be c3bc

I've tried to convert my path using ISOLatin1 encoding, MacOSRoman... but as long as the content path already have 2 separate chars instead of one for ü, any conversion give me 2 chars encoded...

If someone can help, thanks

My configuration : localized in french and using snow leopard.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> urlStringOfVolumeToMount = [urlStringOfVolumeToMount stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
> ```

Unless you specifically need MacRoman for some reason, you should probably be using UTF-8 here.

> ```
> NSMutableArray *content = (NSMutableArray *)[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
> ```
>
> My problem is every path in "content" array containing special chars (ü for example) give me 2 chars encoded : ü becomes u¨

You're expecting composed characters and getting decomposed sequences.

Since you're getting the pathnames from the file-system, this is not a problem: The pathnames are correct as you're receiving them, and as long as you pass them to something that does Unicode right, they will display correctly as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There's no special reason for using MacRoman instead of utf-8 in urlStringOfVolumeToMount. I will change this. The string i'm getting from this are written in files for another system. The string is a path to a movie that does not open if chars are decomposed). There's an interesting post there : http://discussions.info.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2632226&start=15&tstart=0. I finally get around my problem by escaping myself special chars in utf-8 from ü to %c3%bc an then getting an NSData from this string constructing bytes taking care of this escaped chars

Answer (score 0):

Well, four years later I'm struggling with the same thing but for åäö in my case.
Took a lot of time to find the simple solution.

NSString has the necessary comparator built in.

Comparing `aString` with `anotherString` where one comes from the array returned by NSFileManagers `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:` is as simple as:
`if( [aString compare:anotherString] == NSOrderedSame )`

The compare method takes care of making both the strings into a comparable canonical format. In effect making them "if they look the same, they are the same"